# Can 32-bit and 64-bit programs communicate using MSMQ?

Tags: c++, msmq, 32bit-64bit

I have a "server" application that is compiled in 32 bit, and I want it to communicate with a 64 bit "client" application using MSMQ. Is this possible?

I am asking this question because I have attempted have those two applications communicate together using the boost message queue library but it seems like the boost message queue does not support communication between 32 bit and 64 bit applications. This is why I am looking for an alternative solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You may get more feedback on [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault.SE](http://serverfault.com/) for this particular question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the MSMQ interface is suitably abstracted from the underlying architecture that 32bit and 64 systems *should* be able to communicate. This would certainly be the case if they were talking via a network socket even if the lower-level RPC mechanism failed (which it should not).

So long as you're careful with the marshalling and unmarshalling of your datatypes, you should be fine.

Comment: I'm mildly surprised that the boost offering did not work. I've never used it myself, however. A bit of googling suggests that Boost 1.48 should cope better with memory sharing between 32 and 64 bit applications; which version of boost are you working with?

Comment: That shared memory fix might not have solved the queueing issue, mind you.

Comment: I am working with boost 1.49. There is a distinct possibility that the incompatibility between my 32bit and 64bit applications could have been due to my own fault, which is why I felt the need to mention it in my question. I compiled both my applications twice - the 32 bit versions worked with each other and the 64 bit versions worked with each other but when I attempted to mix the 32 and 64 bit apps, they did not seem to be able to access the same message queue.

Comment: Hard to say whether the issue is in your library or the marshalling code at your end. You could try posting an example of the failure; I might not be able to tell if it is really broken, but there are plenty of other boost users here.

Comment: @Rook : You may be thinking of Boost.MPI, which does not have portability issues; however I think the OP is referring to Boost.Interprocess, which _definitely_ would not work the way he wants.